# Visual edit geographic data with geotools

Tags: java, geotools

With JMapFrame I have features for visualizing my geographic data, but I don´t know how to add tools for editing this data, as with a GIS application. Is it possible to do this?

Regards,

Augusto

Answer (score 0):

JMapFrame is apparently a part of an open source toolkit published on http://geotools.org/

As it's open source, you can add any functionality you like. You just have to implement it.